# How to solve this error (missing $)

Tags: tables, errors, superscripts, underscore

This error keeps popping while making my table:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                 $
l.196 \textit{E} & 13.21 \cdot\rho_{dry}$+0.73 \cdot $\% Min$-0.06$\cdot$ ...?
```

This is my code:

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Equations obtained from multiple regression analysis of Elastic modulus (\textit{E}) and Stiffness (\textit{k})}
\label{tab:5}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
Dependent & Multiple regression equation & $r^{2}$ & $Adj r^{2}$ & p- value\\
variable& & & &\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\textit{E} & 13.21 \cdot $\rho_{dry}$+0.73 \cdot $\% Min$-0.06$\cdot$ $\% Org$_{w}$-0.07 $\cdot$ $\% H_{2}O$-55.56$ & 0.96 & 0.95 & 4.8 x $10^{-13}$\\
\textit{k}& 1853.69 $\cdot$ $\rho_{dry}$ + 2.49 $\cdot$ $\% Min$ - 22.29 $\cdot$ $\% Org_{w}$ – 6.54 $\cdot$ $\% H_{2}O$ – 2190.16 & 0.95 & 0.93 & $4.35 x 10^{-12}$\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dollar missing in the column.

```
\textit{E} & $13.21 \cdot \rho_{dry} +0.73 \cdot \% Min-0.06 \cdot \% Org_{w}-0.07 \cdot \% H_{2}O-55.56$ & 0.96 & 0.95 & 4.8 x $10^{-13}$\\
\textit{k}& 1853.69 $\cdot$ $\rho_{dry}$ + 2.49 $\cdot$ $\% Min$ - 22.29 $\cdot$ $\% Org_{w}$ – 6.54 $\cdot$ $\% H_{2}O$ – 2190.16 & 0.95 & 0.93 & $4.35 x 10^{-12}$\\
```

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 4):

A variation of *gernot* answer:

[image]

Instead nested arrays are used macro `\makecell` from package `makecell`. Other small differences are visible with comparison of both MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\[
%\renewcommand\arraycolsep{3pt}
\begin{array}{clccl}
    \toprule
\text{\makecell[b]{Dependent\\variable}}
    &   \text{Multiple regression equation}
        &   r^2
            &   \mathrm{Adj}\;r^2
                &   p\text{-value}                  \\  
    \midrule
E   &   \makecell[lt]{13.21 \cdot \rho_{\mathrm{dry}} + 0.73\cdot\%\mathrm{Min}\\
            -0.06 \cdot\%\mathrm{Org}_w - 0.07\cdot\%\mathrm{H}_2\mathrm{O} - 55.56}
        & 0.96  & 0.95  & 4.8 \times 10^{-13}       \\
    \addlinespace
k   &   \makecell[lt]{1853.69 \cdot \rho_{\mathrm{dry}} + 2.49\cdot\%\mathrm{Min}\\
            -22.29 \cdot \%\mathrm{Org}_w - 6.54\cdot\%\mathrm{H}_2\mathrm{O} - 2190.16}
        & 0.95  & 0.93  & 4.35 \times 10^{-12}      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is caused by a missing `$` sign (`\cdot` has to be used in math mode), which is a bit paradoxical since you use far too many dollar signs. Basically the whole formulas should be put into the same math environment. Here is a rewrite of your tabular.

Note: You had several wrong characters in your table which look like slightly longer minuses but which will probably not show up in your document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\(
\renewcommand\arraycolsep{3pt}
\begin{array}{clccl}
\toprule
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      dep.\\var.
    \end{tabular}
  & \text{Multiple regression equation}
  & r^2
  & \mathrm{Adj}\;r^2
  & \text{$p$-value}
\\\midrule
    E
  & \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      13.21 \cdot \rho_{\text{dry}}
      +0.73 \cdot \%\mathrm{Min}
    \\
      {}-0.06 \cdot \%\mathrm{Org}_w
      -0.07 \cdot \%\mathrm{H}_2\mathrm{O}
      -55.56
    \end{array}
  & 0.96
  & 0.95
  & 4.8\phantom{0}\times 10^{-13}
\\
    k
  & \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}
      1853.69 \cdot \rho_{\text{dry}}
      + 2.49 \cdot \%\mathrm{Min}
    \\
      {}-22.29 \cdot \%\mathrm{Org}_w
      - 6.54 \cdot \%\mathrm{H}_2\mathrm{O}
      - 2190.16
    \end{array}
  & 0.95
  & 0.93
  & 4.35 \times 10^{-12}
\\\bottomrule
\end{array}
\)
\end{document}
```